# python mysqldb not working - no error message

Tags: python, mysql

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?  There are no error messages and the script runs fine, but no record is inserted into the db.  Running the insert query on the database works fine.

Even if i put in a bogus IP or password no error is generated.

This is on windows with python 2.7 and the mysqldb 2.7 windows binaries.

```
import os, sys, time, glob, shlex, subprocess, MySQLdb

try:
    db=MySQLdb.connect(host="my.sql.server.ip.here",user="encoding",passwd="passhere",db="encoding")
except MySQLdb.Error, e:
    print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
    sys.exit (1)

c=db.cursor()
c.execute("""INSERT INTO test (jobid, frame) VALUES (%s, %s)""",("asdf", "s[1]" ) )
c.close ()
db.close ()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Autocommit is disabled. Commit the transaction before disconnecting.